# Fazer pesquisa via POST ao clicar na div

Tags: php, jquery

Estou adaptando o seguinte script:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#getUser').on('click',function(){
        var user_id = $('#user_id').val();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'php/getData.php',
            dataType: "json",
            data:{user_id:user_id},
            success:function(data){
                if(data.status == 'ok'){
                    $('#userName').text(data.result.name);
                    $('#userEmail').text(data.result.email);
                    $('#userPhone').text(data.result.phone);
                    $('#userCreated').text(data.result.created);
                }else{
                    alert("User not found...");
                } 
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="user_id" />
<input type="button" id="getUser" value="Get Details"/>
<div class="user-content">
    <h4>User Details</h4>
    <p>Name: <span id="userName"></span></p>
    <p>Email: <span id="userEmail"></span></p>
    <p>Phone: <span id="userPhone"></span></p>
    <p>Register Date: <span id="userCreated"></span></p>
</div>
```

```html
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['user_id'])){
    $data = array();
 
 /******* Conexão com o bando de dados *******/   
 include "../../Conexao/config.php";
     
 mysqli_select_db($config, $database_config);
 mysqli_set_charset($config,"utf8");
 /******* Conexão com o bando de dados *******/  
    
    //database details
    $dbHost     = $hostname_config;
    $dbUsername = $username_config;
    $dbPassword = $password_config;
    $dbName     = $database_config;
    
    //create connection and select DB
    $db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
    if($db->connect_error){
        die("Unable to connect database: " . $db->connect_error);
    }
    
    //get user data from the database
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = {$_POST['user_id']}");
    
    if($query->num_rows > 0){
        $userData = $query->fetch_assoc();
        $data['status'] = 'ok';
        $data['result'] = $userData;
    }else{
        $data['status'] = 'err';
        $data['result'] = '';
    }
    
    //returns data as JSON format
    echo json_encode($data);
}
?>
```

Ele funciona com o evento "click".
Eu preciso que ele funcione com o TAB do teclado ou ao clicar sobre a div, como nessa consulta de cep:

https://viacep.com.br/exemplo/jquery/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este efeito é conseguido com o evento `blur` que ocorre ao perder o foco do campo de texto.

Seria algo como:

```
$('#user_id').on('blur', function () {
  ...
});
```

### Mais informações

[blur (evento)](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Events/blur)